# JQuery Mobile: selectmenu() and selectmenu('refresh') creating nested selects

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am having a ton of issues with the jQuery mobile selects and dynamic data. I want to have a select that I can enable and disable and dynamically fill.

```
<select id="selectMobileMenu" onchange="functionMobile()" style="width: 100%" class="mobileSelect"></select>
```

The problem is, when I first disable the button to prevent the error: `Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on selectmenu prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'` I get a 2 nested selects within the select.

```
        selectMobile = $('[id=*selectMobileMenu]');
        //Ensure the candidateListBox is defined
        if (selectMobile.data("mobile-selectmenu") === undefined) {
            // not initialized yet, lets do so
            selectMobile.selectmenu('refresh');  //<--- Creates nested select
        }
        selectMobile.selectmenu();  //<--- Creates nested select
        selectMobile.selectmenu('disable');
```

It seems that whenever I call `selectmenu()` or `selectmenu('refresh')` I get a nested select, which is problematic, because I need to call `selectmenu()` and `selectmenu('refresh')`. I could try to remove all the 'ui-disable` classes (which works on some controllers but not others), but I feel like that would make an incredibly brittle control even more so.

Ideas?

Comment: `$('.ui-page-active').trigger('create')`?

Comment: I actually resolved this by trying `$('select#selectMobileMenu').selectmenu();`. I should update the answer, but I wanted to see if there were other ways as well

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me:

```
selectMobile = $('select#selectMobileMenu');

if (selectMobile.data("mobile-selectmenu") === undefined) {
    selectMobile.selectmenu('refresh'); 
}
selectMobile.selectmenu();  
selectMobile.selectmenu('disable');
```